# Chinese and Japanese languages are not correct in Jfree Chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using Jfree chart in my application. The internationalization works perfectly for German,Russian,French...But in Chinese, Japanese the x and y axis texts are looks like square box. How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope you are using the UTF-8 encoding? Sharing the code can help more.

Answer (score 1):

Check the link below, it seems to be talking about the exactly same problem:

http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=109313

> You need to ensure that you are using a font that supports the
>   characters you are trying to display. If you see squares, that's an
>   indication that the font doesn't have glyphs for the unicode character
>   you are trying to show.

Comment: Just now i found the reason of the issue. I am using the linux machine. In windows machine it works perfectly. I can't get the solution for this one. Can any one please help me to how to resolve this issue in linux machine.